# What is the concept behind svelte compilation?

Tags: svelte

I went through your article https://svelte.dev/blog/virtual-dom-is-pure-overhead and few other blogs but they are explain how svelte is better when compared to virtual dom. Whereas what I wanted to understand is its working without comparison to other framework / concepts.

The reason I ask is, seems like svelte is showcasing performance gain in comparison to dom-diffing. Back then, DOM-diffing framework showcased performance gain in comparison to DOM manipulated code.

Where can I documentation / pictorial representation of just svelte compilation?

I tried searching through svelte issues/ questions, medium articles and did not find what I was looking for.

I also looked at https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1011#issuecomment-351262252 but did not find what I was looking for because it explains the details in it, how it was technically implemented.

Comment: In simple terms, during compilation, they identify the updates to modal and emit few code statements that update the relevant DOM element. It actually sounds very intuitive. If you were to ask a newbie developer how he would implement this without any knowledge of existing frameworks, he would probably answered - I would use watchers. But if you probe him a little bit more to come up with something performant, he would have most probably suggested svelte's approach.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to understand it is to look at the code it generates. [Visit the REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f5acc8113ec14bc7946eff9687916fa1?version=3.4.1) and click on the 'JS Output' tab. Note that the update code (the `p` method returned from `create_fragment`) looks like this:

```
if (changed.count) {
  set_data(t1, ctx.count);
}
```

`set_data` is just a wrapper around `textNode.data = ...`. In other words, Svelte generates code that updates the DOM directly upon state changes based on which values changed. It doesn't need to check or regenerate everything, unlike frameworks that use a virtual DOM.

Comment: What is strange to me is that why didn't other frameworks go with this!? I find this a lot simple, intuitive and efficient too. Is there something inherently bad with this approach? Maybe it won't do well when the app gets big?

Comment: On second thoughts, I see why this is doesn't fit for frameworks that rely on virtual DOM like react as they inherently don't want to listen/check for mutations(rather just re-render the UI and leave performance to virtual DOM)